# Expression for Modified Triangle Vegetation Index 2, Landsat 8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator, expression, vegetation-index

I am trying to run the index. In order to get it, I'm using raster calculator. Wrote the expression, but it's not coming rightly.

Could one check and revert whether the expression is right?

```
((1.8 * ("NIR" - "Green")) - (3.75 * ("Red" - "Green"))) / (SquareRoot((Square((2 *  "NIR") +  1)) -  ((6 * "NIR") - (5 * SquareRoot("Red")) - 0.5)))
```

Comment: If you provide a reference defining the Triangular Vegetation Index, someone might check it for you.

Comment: Hello wingnut, what do you mean by providing a reference?

Comment: A link to a site that explains the TVI.

Comment: Paper: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJ6t2QDMIzH9gYyLXhlWIRklUb99KqCn/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(1.8 * ("NIR"-"Green") -3.75 * ("Red"-"Green")) / (SquareRoot(Square(2 * "NIR" + 1)-(6 * "NIR" - 5 * sqrt("Red")) - 0.5))
```

- based on *Bagheri, Ahmadi, Alavipanah & Omid **2013**.*

Comment: Calculation Failed: (1.8 * ("LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B5.TIF" - "LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B3.TIF") - 3.75 * ("LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B4.TIF" - "LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B3.TIF")) / (SquareRoot(Square(2 * "LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B5.TIF" + 1)- (6 * "LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B5.TIF" - 5 * SquareRoot("LC08_L1TP_137042_20200330_20200409_01_T1_B4.TIF")) - 0.5))

Comment: It looks like the correct formula, and the brackets match. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/image-analyst/mtvi2.htm and https://www.indexdatabase.de/search/?s=TVI have different formulae for MTVI2 - they are the same as each other, but not the same as this. I can only suggest that the rasters are not aligned. Was there an error message apart from 'Calculation Failed'?

Comment: 000539 : Error message from Python
It's getting extremely frustrating, Glenn. Tried 14 times till now. I matched brackets repeatedly and still, no result!

Comment: Do it piece by piece. Test the denominator. Test the numerator. If the denominator is zero, it may fail, so make sure there is always something there in the NIR and Red (that would be a square root of a negative number) and that the 'nodata' value is set. You may need a conditional test for zero in the denominator. Use a fixed value for the output in that case. Don't give up!

Comment: Glenn, foolishness has many spectrums. The formula was correct from the very beginning. The folder name had space in between. -_-

Comment: Yes, that happens!